# .net Reference Web in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, n-layer

I am writing an n-layer app/site and in my Common class library I need to call on NetSqlAzMan Web reference but that cannot be imported into a class library, only into a website type project.
One way to get around it is to make my Common layer a site but that just doesn't seem right.
How to properly implement that?
I am using VS2010 Pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the project type of your class library is Client Profile instead of a normal one.

Client profile class libraries are not allowed to reference `System.Web`

If you change the target platform to ".NET Framework 4" you should be able to reference `System.Web`

Comment: Yes you are correct. It is currently set to 4.0 client. Thanks for pointing that out.